# Pass record value to controller using lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm new to using lightning and am writing a component that overrides a custom object detail button. I'm able to successfully override the detail view with my component using: `<force:recordView recordId="{!v.recordId}" type="FULL"/>`

I have two buttons that I have added, which call action methods in my apex controller. Each button returns a record id that I will use to navigate to when the methods are executed.

My question, is how can I pass a value to my action method from the recordView?

Here is my component:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName" controller="SSOViewOverrideController" access="global">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/> 
<div class="slds-card">
    <div class="slds-m-around--xx-large">
        <div class="slds-form--stacked">
            <div class="slds-m-around--medium">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.gotoContact}">Go To Contact</button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.createCase}">Create Case</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="SSO__x" />
</div> 
</aura:component>
```

Here is my component controller:

```
({
 doInit: function(cmp) {
     var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
     navEvt.setParams({
         "recordId": cmp.get("v.recordId"),
         "slideDevName": "detail"
     });
     navEvt.fire();      
}, 
gotoContact: function(cmp) {
    var action = ccmp.get('c.getContact'); 
    action.setParams({ guidId : cmp.get("v.guid__c") });
},
createCase: function(cmp) {

}
})
```

Here is my apex controller action method:

```
@auraEnabled
public static Id getContact(string guidId) {
    Id retval;
    Contact[] cList = CreateCaseContactUtil.searchContactByGUID(guidId);
    if(cList.size() > 0) {
        retval = cList[0].Id;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

I need to pass the record field value `guid__c` into my apex controller action method, which returns a contact Id that I will then want to navigate to that record when the button is clicked.

The recordView is showing the `guid__c` value on the page, but have not been able to pass it to my action method and get the id back to navigate to contact record.

Comment: There are few issues in your implementation as of now, I have added details on how you can modify this and achieve what you want with couple of options. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading your implementation right, then you have got few things wrong here in your implementation. You are *not really viewing what is in your component*, rather when your component is initialized, you are actually redirecting the flow using `force:navigateToSobject` in your `donInit` function to the record id mentioned in the function. So you never are in your component.

Going back to `force:recordView`, it is a read only representation and does not let you to fetch any further details on the rendered layout viz., fetch specific field values from the view. Though you will have access to the *body* of the component, but traversing through it to find a field's value will be more cumbersome. If you refer to the [documentation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/213905/54851), it mentions as below.

> If you want granular control over displaying of specific fields, we recommend using lightning:outputField instead.

As for your issue of passing a value from your view to the controller, you have got couple of options.

**Option 1 - Modification in your current implementation**

Assuming that you want a *detail layout* using `force:recordView`, you can make a server call in your `doInit` function to fetch the *guid* field and populate it on your component. And then when you click the button, use this field's value to pass on to apex controller. Your code will look something like this:

Attribute declaration on component:

```
<aura:attribute name="guid" type="String" />
```

In your existing *doInit*, modify it as:

```
doInit: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var action = cmp.get('c.getGUID');
    action.setParams({ recordId : cmp.get("v.recordId") }
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            cmp.set("v.guid", response.getReturnValue()); // you are setting the guid from server here
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

And in your apex controller:

```
@auraEnabled
public static String getGUID(String recordId) {
    // select guid from sso__x where id = :recordId;
    // return the guid as retrieved
}
```

Now you have **guid** available with your component as an attribute on it, which you can use anywhere in any of the JS function.

So when you click the button, you can fetch the guid in your JS function:

```
gotoContact: function(cmp) {
    var action = ccmp.get('c.getContact'); 
    action.setParams({ guidId : cmp.get("v.guid") }); // notice this line
    // call your apex method
    // use navigateToSobject here to redirect to the contact id as retrieved.
}
```

Using this approach, you are using *recordView* along with a bit of your customization. However note that this may not be most efficient way as this approach is actually making a server trip twice, once for loading the fields with record view and then in your *doInit* function. But with this approach you easily achieve the **detail layout** functionality without writing anything around how to render the fields.

**Option 2 - Implement using lightning:recordEditForm**

With this approach, you will need to write all your fields which you want to display on the page. You can use *lightning:inputField* with some styling to make it read only, so that it aligns with detail layout, associate the input fields with an *aura:id* and then retrieve the values in your JS function. You can find more details using *lightning:recordEditForm* and how to fetch values from it in JS function in this [answer here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/213905/54851).

Answer (score 0):

Quick Tip: You will be better off using the [lightning:recordEditForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordEditForm.htm?search_text=form) component, which has several actions you can use where you can pass parameters to your apex controller and have control of where you want to navigate after record creation/edit, and so on.

For example, you can call the response Object which is returned onsuccess, and fetch the record id in order to navigate to a specific page.
component.cmp

```
<lightning:recordEditForm recordId="003XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" objectApiName="Contact" nameofAction="{!c.takeAction}">
```

component.js

```
takeAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    //Do something with the response object, such as, fetching the ID
    //and calling your server side action
},
```

Comment: Thank you @glls, I switched to `<lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="SSO__x" />` and it displays just like the recordView which is good. Any examples on how to pass my field value to the action method?

Comment: you might want to follow up with a new post, and how you are accessing the response object to call a server side action from from your method.

Comment: @Dman100 If you have used inputfield implementation along with, you can associate and id on the field and use that to retrieve the value in JS controller. Updating your post with the implementation will help to provide further details.

Comment: @Jayant Das, I updated my original post to include the change to `recordEditForm`. However, I haven't successfully passed the field value from the record to the JS controller as a parameter in my action method.

Comment: ccmp is just a typo right? again, as mentioend in the answer, you can call the response object on form submission to get the field valus (of the submitted data, please check the documentation linked in the post and upadte your post with how you are attempting to pass the field value, as is, I dont really see what/how you are trying to pass the guid__c