# Easiest way to get a value from a lightning:inputField

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inputfield, lightning-recordeditform

I want to get the value from a lightning:inputField, but I can't.

Component:

```
<aura:attribute name="myAttribute" type="String"/>
{!v.myAttribute}

<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Lead" onsubmit="{!c.submit}">
    <lightning:inputField aura:id="myatt" fieldName="MyAtt__c" value="{!v.myAttribute}" label="Attribute"/>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

It seems like you can't set the value of an inputField? I've tried accessing this value both within the component using `{!v.myAttribute}`, in the controller with `component.get("v.myAttribute")` and with `myAtt = component.find("myatt"); myVal = myAtt.get("v.value")`.

All are undefined.

Here is full code:

component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForRecordHome">
<aura:attribute name="myAttribute" type="String"/>

    {!v.myAttribute}

<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Lead" onsubmit="{!c.submit}">
    <lightning:inputField aura:id="myAtt" fieldName="Company" value="{!v.myAttribute}" label="Attribute" onchange="{!c.myChange}"/>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Controller:

```
({
    submit: function(component, event, helper){
        console.log('hi');
    },
    myChange: function(component, event, helper){
        console.log('hi');
        var myEle = component.find("myAtt");
        console.log(myEle);
        var myAttri = component.find("myAtt").get("v.value");
        console.log(myAttri);
    }
})
```

Comment: It is working for me. there might be something else which is causing the problem.

Comment: Would you mind commenting out your `myAttribute` attribute out of your code, and removing the `value` attribute from the input field component? Tell us if you still get undefined results then.

Comment: If that solved your issue, please mark my answer as the solution. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming your `lightning:inputField` tag has the `aura:id` of `firstNameField`, for example, you'd get its value with:

```
var firstName = component.find("firstNameField").get("v.value");
```

In your second example, in your `find` call, you are using an uppercase `A`, whereas in your code the `aura:id` has a lowercase `a`:

```
"myAtt" != "myatt"
```

I've had some questions regarding the `recordEditForm` before too. [**This might be useful**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/213804/how-can-one-validate-recordeditform-fields-before-submitting-them-to-the-platf).

Edit:

I think your attribute might also be conflicting. Would you mind commenting out your `myAttribute` attribute out of your code, and removing the `value` attribute from the input field component?

Comment: Thanks Renato - actually the spelling mistake was only in the question, not in my actual code. In my code, I have the correct Id name, I retrieve the element in question, but the value is 'undefined'.

Comment: That's weird. Can you post the rest of your component and controller source codes?

Comment: Yes, I've added the full code above.

Answer (score 2):

When using the [lightning:recordEditform](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_inputField.htm), in order to fetch values, I usually leverage event.getSource()

for example:

component input field

```
<lightning:inputField aura:id="countyId" fieldName="country__c"
                                                      variant="label-hidden"
                                                      onchange="{!c.StateChange}"
```

controller.js

```
StateChange  : function(component, event, helper) {  
        console.log(event.getSource().get("v.value"))

    }
```

the following articles might be of help:

- [Event Handling in Base Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_base_events.htm)
- [Which Button Was Pressed?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_which_button_pressed.htm)