# How to Re-submit the lightning:recordEditForm after event.preventDefault()

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-recordeditform, data-service

I am stuck in a issue where i have to add custom validation on fields in lightning:recordEditForm. I am using the onsubmit method of lightning:recordEditForm to check the fields values and if the validation fails i am using event.preventDefault() to stop the form from submission.however once i use the event.preventDefault() i am not able to submit the form again. i have also tried the js submit() method which submits the form but it does not fires the onsubmit() method of the recordEditForm (i want the onsubmit() method of the form to be called because i can get the fields values there easily).

Comment: Have you taken a look at this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/213905/54851) almost on the same requirement?

Comment: Yes,but as i mentioned i want the onsubmit() method of the form to be called but using js submit() method does not fires the onsubmit() method.