# How to do field validation on lightning:recordEditForm with lightning:inputField

Tags: lightning-aura-components, validation, lightning-inputfield, lightning-recordeditform

**Background**

I have a lightning component with a `lightning:recordEditForm` for creating new `Opportunity` records.

The `lightning:recordEditForm` contains many `lightning:inputField` 's

I would like to perform basic required field validation on the form, using code like this:

```
     let isValid = true;
     let fields = cmp.find("requiredField"); // gets all required fields

     for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
         if (fields[i] != null) {
             if (fields[i].get('v.validity').valid == false) {
                 fields[i].showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
                 isValid = false;
             }
         }
     }
```

But I am unable to access property `validity` / `valid` on the `lightning:inputField`

And I am unable to call the `showHelpMessageIfInvalid()` method on the  `lightning:inputField`

**Questions**

1. How should I approach form validation using `lightning:recordEditForm`
2. How can I get each field to display the red border if the field is not valid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not able to use `validity` on [lightning:inputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/documentation) because the attribute is not supported on this component, instead its an attribute for [lighting:input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/specification).

For validating `lightning:inputField` with `lightning:recordEditForm`, you can refer to **[this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/213905/54851)** which provides a perspective as how you can validate values entered on the component.

For the error scenarios, you can utilize the CSS that's available for the purpose. You can refer to more on this on [SLDS documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/form-element/#Error) for the component from where it inherits the styling.

Answer (score 3):

One way to catch and throw error messages without having to write any custom code is to include `<lightning:messages/>` in the component and set the fields to required at the object level.  [Heres an example of that](http://peterknolle.com/apexless-lightning-components/)

If you are unable to do that for your org my advice would be to switch to lightning:input as it is one of the few tags that currently supports [custom client side validation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_validate_fields.htm)

Comment: But the intention is to use recordEditForm. So You are asking to make not to use data services. Let me know If I am wrong here...Because with recordeditform, we cant use ligheing input.

Comment: @user533 did you got anything for this?

Comment: You could always leverage recordForm and just specify the fields you want included instead of manually creating them in recordEditForm