# Manually check for validation in a lightning-record-form

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a modal with a `lightning-record-edit-form` and I want to show a spinner as soon as the Save button is clicked, keeping it consistent with how it is in standard Salesforce.

I have an `onclick` handler on the Save button to show the spinner and I remove it as soon as it enters the `onsuccess` or `onerror` handler.

However, there's an issue when there are form validity errors, then, the spinner never gets removed. Ideally, I'd need an `oninvalid` handler on the form itself or something, but the `lightning-record-form` variations don't have that method.

Then, I tried to manually check whether the fields are valid, but `lightning-input-field` doesn't have a `checkValidity` method. I know it's just using `lightning-input` under the hood, but I can't seem to access those elements with `this.template.querySelector` (or with `document` if that even works).

So my question is: Can we somehow manually check for validation in a `lightning-record-form` or a variation on the form?

Comment: Check if this answers you question - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/234487/how-to-do-field-validation-on-lightningrecordeditform-with-lightninginputfield

Comment: Validity is not supported for lightning-input-field, refer the above answer to get some perspectives on how to approach custom validations for lightning-input-field

Comment: @prabuddhkumar It doesn't because the answer there is to do the validation logic manually in js, which is obviously not something I'm going to do / maintain / ...

Comment: ok, how did you deduce that it's due to "form validity errors", could you add the error/screenshot/example ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onerror` attribute of your `lightning-record-edit-form` to stop the spinner.

*HTML*

```
.......
.......
<!-- Loading Spinner-->
<template if:true={loading}>
    <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading..." size="medium"></lightning-spinner>
</template>
......
<lightning-record-edit-form onerror={handleError}
......
......
```

*JS*

```
loading = false;
......
......
handleError(evt){
    this.loading = false;
}
......
```

Comment: I'm already using `onerror` and it's working for the back-end validation. 
I'm referring to the front-end form validation here.

Comment: In other words, front-end form validation errors don't trigger the `onerror` method.

Comment: You may have to edit your question to add more details to code specifying the issue.

Comment: @vince what kind of front-end validation you have? It would be best to add them in your question.

Comment: It's just the standard `lightning-record-form` functionality.

Comment: Required fields for example

Comment: I didn't add it explicitly though, it's just that sf adds it under the hood, hence the standard functionality of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you ever figured this out, but if you move the spinner start to the onsubmit event for the form itself, the spinner won't display until after field-level validation occurs. Any custom validation rules will trip the onerror event and stop the spinner.