# How to achieve custom error handling on lightning:inputField base components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, error-messages

With the [record:EditForm lightning base component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm), one can now easily ensure that picklist values are displayed dynamically based on the record type that is chosen.

Instead of having to leverage the UI API explicitly, all I need to do is have the following markup:

```
<aura:attribute name="RecordTypeId" type="String" access="public"/>
    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm" recordTypeId="{!v.RecordTypeId}" objectApiName="Interactions__c" class="slds-p-top_small"> 
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Interaction_Category__c" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="RecordTypeId" value="{!v.RecordTypeId}" class="slds-hide" />          
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

and then in the .js controller, I can pass in the record type Id to the relevant value attribute like so:

```
    doInit : function(component, event, helper)
    {
        var fullURL = window.location.href;
        var recordTypeId = fullURL.substring(fullURL.indexOf("recordTypeId") + 13,fullURL.indexOf("recordTypeId") + 31);
        console.log('recordTypeId is: ' + recordTypeId);
        if (recordTypeId != null) 
        { 
            component.set('v.RecordTypeId', recordTypeId); 
        }
```

So now, the field 'Interaction Category' will dynamically display the picklist values that correspond to the selected record type of the sObject. This is very helpful.

**However, unfortunately, [as per the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField), there is no 'required' attribute for lightning:inputField.** I could make the field itself required but I want to conditionally make it a required field.

I have been trying with setCustomValidity or set("v.errors") as per this [example](https://techevangel.com/2019/03/17/custom-fields-validation-in-lightning-component/) but nothing seems to be working - in the console.logs, I can't even get past the .setCustomValidity method.

What is the best approach to have a lighting:inputField component have error handling / conditional required rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using the logic as outlined in this duplicate post here: [How can one validate 'recordEditForm' fields before submitting them to the platform?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/213804/how-can-one-validate-recordeditform-fields-before-submitting-them-to-the-platf/213905#213905). Lastly, this doc is also relevant: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_validate_fields.htm.